# XRDP and Cinnamon running in software rendering mode

Tags: debian, xorg, cinnamon, xrdp

When i connect via xrdp 0.9.1-9+deb9u3 -> xorg from windows RDP client to Debian 9.5 i have this [image: this] message on Desktop

> Running in software rendering mode
>
> Cinnamon is currently running without video hardware acceleration and
>   as a result, you may observe much higher than normal CPU usage.
>
> There could be a problem with your drivers or some other issue. For
>   the best experience, it is recommended that you only use this mode for
>   troubleshooting purposes.

How avoid this problem?

Comment: You mean, how can you suppress the warning message?

Comment: Not only supress, increase speed too

Comment: Using remote viewing software, like RDP, involves emulating a video card in software. You cannot use hardware acceleration on the remote system, which is the one with the warning message.

Answer (score 1):

There is an experimental GPU-enabled version of xorgxrdp (part of xrdp). Details are in https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/1029, code itself https://github.com/jsorg71/xorgxrdp/tree/glamor

Look and feel looks way better in my setup, your mileage and support of graphic adapters might vary. Be ready for high CPU usage by xrdp when something is actively updating on the screen, ie watching video.